# 2checkout payment verfication on demo account not working

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, payment-processing, 2checkout

i am having demo account on 2checkout.i am require to accept online payment via 2checkout. so for that i am testing code with demo account. the problem is that on demo account i got message the order processsed sucessfully but when i verify the same on myside using documentation it is always failed.

below is html code to make payment online

```
 <form action='https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='sid' value='202351337'>
    <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='1'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='1'>
    <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Buy from 2CO' >
    </form>
```

below is verification code taken from 2checkout official documentation

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
$hashSecretWord='james007'; //2Checkout Secret Word
$hashSid=202351337; //2Checkout account number
$hashTotal=100.00; //Sale total to validate against
$hashOrder=1; //2Checkout Order Number
$StringToHash = strtoupper(md5($hashSecretWord . $hashSid . $hashOrder . $hashTotal));
echo "<br/> And StringToHash is $StringToHash <br/>";
if ($StringToHash != $_REQUEST['key'])
{
$result = 'Fail - Hash Mismatch';
}
else 
{
$result = 'Success - Hash Matched';
}

echo $result;
```

i always to message Fail-Hash Mismatch

Answer (score 1):

your giving `$hashOrder=1;`

but order number 1 will work only for Demo sales
if your Post URL like below then only   `$hashOrder=1;` will work
(https://sandbox.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase' method='post'>).

but your using `<form action='https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase' method='post'>`. that means your live sale.
in this case `$hashOrder=$_REQUEST['hashOrder'];`

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is due to the fact that you are setting the `hashTotal` as a number, not a string. Try changing that line to this:

```
$hashTotal='100.00';
```